# How to add a subview in drop-down style in a table below each row on row-click event?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xcode4

How to add a subview in drop-down style in a table below each row on row-click event?

Ill add more details: **When I click on a row, a subview should be appear in drop-down style below the row where I can put more Buttons and text-boxes. This should happen for every row in the table.**

Thanks.

Comment: Is there rows are fixed or variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/vppdropdown

It features exactly what you've described

Comment: Is there no way to change size of cells dynamically through coding? I cant add new libraries in my project. Its a security issue.

Comment: you can define size dynamically but on what basis? Is there particular rows  that would have different size from another